# How do you check to see if a value exists in a dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python

Really dumb and annoying question. I have this dictionary:

```
{
    'GIS': {
        'maxAge': 86400,
        'currentPrice': 60.3,
        'targetHighPrice': 67.0,
        'targetLowPrice': 45.0,
    }
}
```

I am trying to check if the targetMeanPrice is in the dictionary. If it is, is there a value. Then print the value. When I run my code the if statement gets ignored and the print statement in the else condition gets executed. Am I overcomplicating things?

see code:

```
if 'targetMeanPrice' in financialData['GIS'].values():
    print("hi")
    if(financialData.isnull(financialData['targetMeanPrice'].values)): # if the value of the target mean is not equal to null
        target = float(financialData['targetMeanPrice'].values)

    print("this is the targetMeanPrice:",target)) 

else:
      print("No targetMeanPrice here")
```

Comment: You get the error `KeyError: 'targetMeanPrice'` because `targetMeanPrice` is not a key in the dictionary you provided. The only key in `financialData` is `GIS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first condition should be

```
if 'targetMeanPrice' in financialData['GIS'].keys():
```

which more succinctly is just

```
if 'targetMeanPrice' in financialData['GIS']:
```

To reach that nested value safely, I think you want

```
target = financialData.get('GIS', {}).get('targetMeanPrice', None)
if target:
    # found it
else:
    # didn't find it
```

Comment: You are a god. This is it. Thanks mate @CoryKramer

Answer (score 1):

You keep calling `values` on dictionaries where you don't actually want the values yet.  Don't do that!  :)

```
if 'targetMeanPrice' in financialData['GIS']:
    target = financialData['GIS']['targetMeanPrice']
    print("this is the targetMeanPrice:", target) 
else:
    print("No targetMeanPrice here")
```

Or rather than testing before you get the value, just `get` with a default:

```
target = financialData['GIS'].get('targetMeanPrice', None)
if target is not None:
    print("this is the targetMeanPrice:", target) 
else:
    print("No targetMeanPrice here")
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to just check it do it like this:

```
if 'targetMeanPrice' in financialData['GIS']:
```

also it seems that your code is not well tabed:

```
if (financialData.isnull(financialData['targetMeanPrice'].values)):
    target = float(financialData['targetMeanPrice'].values)
    print("this is the targetMeanPrice:", target))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `try` statement would work well here. If GIS doesn’t exist in financialData or targetMeanPrice doesn’t exist in GIS, the code in the `except` clause is triggered by the `KeyError`.

```
try:
    target = financialData[“GIS”][“targetMeanPrice”]
    print("this is the targetMeanPrice:", target)
except KeyError:
    print("No targetMeanPrice here")
```